# How can I rotate the x axis label in this jqplot script

Tags: javascript, jqplot

Below is part of a script based on the jqplot bar plot examples. I am trying to rotate the x axis tick lables as they are overlapping I have imported the TickRender plugin, however when I 
add the following code to the script below the graph fails to print at all.

Can you tell how I can do this correctly.

```
tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
  tickOptions: {
     angle: -30,
     fontSize: '10pt'
  }
```

//jqplot script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1 = [2314,2053,94,70,2541,2626,2551,2515,2147,116,82,2536,2560,2558,2465,2127,103,73,2546,2554,2583,2527,2235,104,88,2515,2604,2641,2532,2142];
        var ticks = ['01/11/2012','02/11/2012','03/11/2012','04/11/2012','05/11/2012','06/11/2012','07/11/2012','08/11/2012','09/11/2012','10/11/2012','11/11/2012','12/11/2012','13/11/2012','14/11/2012','15/11/2012','16/11/2012','17/11/2012','18/11/2012','19/11/2012','20/11/2012','21/11/2012','22/11/2012','23/11/2012','24/11/2012','25/11/2012','26/11/2012','27/11/2012','28/11/2012','29/11/2012','30/11/2012'];

        plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
            // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
            animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true }

            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                tickOptions: {
                angle: -30,
                fontSize: '10pt'
                }

            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                }



            },
            highlighter: { show: false }
        });

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
 axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -90,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
    }
```

OR

```
axes: {
       xaxis: {
              renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              ticks: ticks,
              tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
              tickOptions: {
                           angle: -90,
                           fontSize: '10pt'
                           }
              }
      }
```

OR

```
axes: {
           xaxis: {
                  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                  ticks: ticks,
                  rendererOptions:{
                                 tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                                 tickOptions: {
                                              angle: -90,
                                              fontSize: '10pt'
                                              }
                                 }
                }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I must be doing something else wrong I normally write in python but I a using javascript for the good looking graphics I am going through a few tutorials so will update the call when I find out what the problem is.

Comment: If you don't include jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js then the axes won't be rotated but always render horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Include the below files from http://www.jqplot.com/examples/rotated-tick-labels.php

```
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqplot.chartCode.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
```